# Unable to setup Django in production on EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

I have set up an EC2 instance with Ubuntu and able to login via ssh.

Now I have installed Apache, MySQL (worked fine) and  Django also tried to configure it to run with apache. I have tried doing so with mod-wsgi but it still shows a apache default page instead of django (Congratulation ! It works) page. Can someone please provide me instructions for how to setup all this after login into EC2 via SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a tutorial provided by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

You need to make sure the apache config file is in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ or wherever your apache configuration files rest.

Another silly problem and this might be your issue is whenever I start a new instance of EC2 there is always a config called "000-default" already in the apache sites-enabled. This needs to be DELETED or DISABLED for apache to read from your config instead.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: @ManjitKumar how to enable our own .conf file?

Comment: did you try `sudo a2ensite example.com.conf`

[link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

For a example check the Step 2 of this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html). yum + git + pip + python requirements

Comment: link provided by you is good for local setup but this doesn't solve my issue with configuration of mod-wsgi with apache.